# How can I access $stateParams from a service in AngularJS?

Tags: angular-ui-router, angularjs-service

This is my service:

```
MetronicApp.factory('ItemService', ['$http', '$sessionStorage', '$stateParams', function($http, $sessionStorage, $stateParams) {

return {
    save: function(data, success, error) {
        return $http.post(baseUrl + '/shops/' + $sessionStorage.currentShop.id + '/menus/' + $stateParams.menuId + '/categories/' +  $stateParams.categoryId + '/items', data).success(success).error(error);
    },
    update: function(data, success, error) {
        return $http.put(baseUrl + '/items/' + data.id, data).success(success).error(error);
    },
    saveTranslation: function(data, success, error) {
        return $http.post(baseUrl + '/itemTranslation', data).success(success).error(error);
    },
    get: function(itemId, success, error) {
        return $http.get(baseUrl + '/items/' + itemId).success(success).error(error);
    },

    getAll: function(categoryId, success, error) {
        console.log("Menu id is: " + $stateParams.menuId);
        return $http.get(baseUrl + '/shops/' + $sessionStorage.currentShop.id + '/menus/' + $stateParams.menuId + '/categories/' +  $stateParams.categoryId + '/items').success(success).error(error);
    }
};
}]);
```

I want to be able to use $stateParams.menuId in getAll method. At that time, url is:

```
/menus/54/categories/56/items
```

But $stateParams is null. How can I get them?

Comment: Hi! What is your route setup? is menuId in the url of the view?

Comment: I tried on plunker building a service and injecting $stateParams with angular.service, and that way works, but if I build the service using a factory it doesn't get inyected, as you said.
Sorry for the previous comment. It's useless.

Comment: Checkout this [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/yzEhDPZBufSwSKF5Z3Sj/preview). 
The controller defined in 'home.list' state is using ItemService service (Log parameter's value to console)
The link "List" on "The Homey Page" pass MenuId as a parameter.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this problem would be to pass in the stateParams from the controller at the time you are executing service functions.  Just make it a parameter on the functions that need this data, and then provide it when executing those functions.

```
MetronicApp.factory('ItemService', ['$http', '$sessionStorage', function($http, $sessionStorage) {

return {
    save: function(data, stateParams, success, error) {
        return $http.post(baseUrl + '/shops/' + $sessionStorage.currentShop.id + '/menus/' + stateParams.menuId + '/categories/' +  stateParams.categoryId + '/items', data).success(success).error(error);
    },
    update: function(data, stateParams, success, error) {
        return $http.put(baseUrl + '/items/' + data.id, data).success(success).error(error);
    },
    saveTranslation: function(data, stateParams, success, error) {
        return $http.post(baseUrl + '/itemTranslation', data).success(success).error(error);
    },
    get: function(itemId, stateParams, success, error) {
        return $http.get(baseUrl + '/items/' + itemId).success(success).error(error);
    },

    getAll: function(categoryId, stateParams, success, error) {
        console.log("Menu id is: " + stateParams.menuId);
        return $http.get(baseUrl + '/shops/' + $sessionStorage.currentShop.id + '/menus/' + stateParams.menuId + '/categories/' +  stateParams.categoryId + '/items').success(success).error(error);
    }
};
}]);
```